# How to speed up splitting one column to create a new one?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

There is a DataFrame containing `last_element` and `root`.

```
import pandas as pd

df_test = pd.DataFrame({"last_element":["2000A01.2 B003", "8000N02 B001"]*100000, "root":[None, "8000N02"]*100000})

df_test.head()

+----+----------------+---------+
|    | last_element   | root    |
|----+----------------+---------|
|  0 | 2000A01.2 B003 |         |
|  1 | 8000N02 B001   | 8000N02 |
|  2 | 2000A01.2 B003 |         |
|  3 | 8000N02 B001   | 8000N02 |
|  4 | 2000A01.2 B003 |         |
+----+----------------+---------+
```

If `root` is empty, we can take it from `last_element`. The value before space is always the `root`.

I already have a solution, but want to ask if someone has a faster one as on real-world data it takes more than a minute to calculate.

---

### Solution 1 - Function

```
%%timeit

df_test = pd.DataFrame({"last_element":["2000A01.2 B003", "8000N02 B001"]*100000, "root":[None, "8000N02"]*100000})

def fill_root(row):
    if pd.isna(row.root) & pd.notna(row.last_element):
        return row.last_element.split(' ')[0]
    else:
        return row.root

df_test.assign(new_root = lambda x: x.apply(fill_root, axis=1))
```

**Time**:

```
5.14 s ± 41.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

---

### Solution 2 - Apply

```
%%timeit

df_test['new_root'] = df_test.apply(lambda row: row.last_element.split(' ')[0] if pd.isna(row.root) else row.root, axis=1)
```

**Time**:

```
3.67 s ± 21.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mask and `df.loc`

```
mask = df_test['root'].isnull()
df_test.loc[mask,'root'] = df_test.loc[mask, 'last_element'].str.split(' ').str[0]


# timeit
def function(df_test):
    mask = df_test['root'].isnull()
    df_test.loc[mask,'root'] = df_test.loc[mask, 'last_element'].str.split(' ').str[0]

%timeit function(df_test)
11.6 ms ± 494 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this solutions is the fastest. Upvote and accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You could try with `np.where`

```
df['new'] = np.where(df['root'].isna(),df['last_element'].str.split().str[0],df['root'])
```

Or

```
df['root'].mask(df['root'].isna(),df['last_element'].str.split().str[0],inplace=True)
```

---

Timing

```
#%timeit df_test['new_root'] = df_test.apply(lambda row: row.last_element.split(' ')[0] if pd.isna(row.root) else row.root, axis=1)
2.97 s ± 101 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
#%timeit df['new_root'] = df['root'].mask(df['root'].isna(),df['last_element'].str.split().str[0])
170 ms ± 348 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
#%timeit df['new_root'] =  np.where(df['root'].isna(),df['last_element'].str.split().str[0],df['root'])
172 ms ± 2.75 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Thank you also very much BENY. Really liked your 2 solutions as well but I accepted Kevins as it was even faster. But again, Thanks and *upvote* :-)